# Make Newman-Penrose scalars definite spin weight

Tags: general-relativity

Reading through the original [GHP paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1666410), I notice that some of the [Newman-Penrose scalars](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Spin-coefficient_formalism) do not have definite spin weight. For example,
\begin{equation}
\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{2}\left(n^il^k\nabla_kl_i+m^il^k\nabla_km^*_i\right),
\end{equation}
does not have definite spin weight as, e.g. $n^il_i=1\neq0$ so that when
we transform $l_i\to\xi\xi^*l_i$ (where $\xi$ is a complex number), we also have terms like $l^k\nabla\left(\xi\xi^*\right)$ in the transformed $\alpha$ scalar.

Besides the approach taken in GHP, where new derivative operators (''thorn'' and ''edth'') are defined which incorporate $\alpha$, is there another way to make $\alpha$ a scalar of definite spin weight (e.g. through the addition of another Newman-Penrose scalar, etc)?

EDIT:

I would be happy to have a way to construct definite spin weight objects from combinations of linear perturbations of the Newman-Penrose scalars about a type D background.

I've been reading through a recent paper [on the stability of Kerr spacetime](https://inspirehep.net/record/1724549). There, the authors claim to define a properly spin-weighted version of a linear perturbation that is very closely related to a linear perturbation of $\alpha$ in Sec 3.1. Their last paragraph at the end of Sec 3.1 explains why their quantity has a definite spin weight, but I do not understand what they are saying.